# Get posts of an specific term of a custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-taxonomy, query, terms

I'm new at Wordpress development and I was wondering (and trying to solve this) for a long time, so maybe you can help me.

My WP use a custom post type named Products. And there is a custom taxonomy with a lot of terms that describe that products.

i.e:

- Products (custom post type)
- ----Product line (custom taxonomy)
- -----------Cardline (term in custom taxonomy)
- -----------Boneline (term in custom taxonomy)
- -----------Odoline (term in custom taxonomy)
- -----------Gineline (term in custom taxonomy)

So, I was able to list all the terms of my custom taxonomy, and to do a while loop to list all the posts inside each term.

However, I was looking to a while loop to list the posts that are related to only one of my custom taxonomy's terms. For example: I want to list only the "international books".

I've tried a lot of solutions, but I still can't get it. Do you have any idea that may help me? I'm working on this. But I can't get anything.

```
  <?php

  $args = array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'line',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'cardline' )
        ),
    ),
    'post_type' => 'prod'
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( have_posts() ) {

    $term = $query->queried_object;

    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        //Output my posts
        the_title();
        the_content();
    endwhile;
}

//RESET YOUR QUERY VARS
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You created a new query and assigned it to `$query`, but your loop does not output the contents of that query object. Refer to [**WP_Query: Multiple Loops**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Multiple_Loops) example for the correct syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the *methods* of *your* query instance, rather than the global functions (which are merely wrappers for the global `$wp_query`):

```
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {

    $term = $query->queried_object;

    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
        //Output my posts
        the_title();
        the_content();
    endwhile;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that works exactly in the way I need it!